# Cannot talk to elements inside xib

Tags: ios, iphone, interface-builder, xib

I am still learning interface builder.

I created a xib containing a button, a progress bar and a spinner. Lets call this xib MyToolbar.xib. I created classes for that xib (MyToolbar.h and .m). Inside the xib, I set the toolbar’s class to MyToolbar. Inside the xib I set File’s Owner to MyToolbar. I connected outlets to all elements and put them on the header.

**The class header is this:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyToolbar : UIToolbar

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressBar;

@end
```

**this is the implementation**

```
#import “MyToolbar.h"
@implementation MyToolbar

- (id)init {

  self = [super init];

  if (self) {

    self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyToolbar"
                                          owner:self
                                        options:nil]
            objectAtIndex:0];

  }

  return self;
}
```

Now I create the object on the main class

```
  MyToolbar *toolbar = [[MyToolbar alloc] init];
```

at this point, toolbar is not nil but toolbar.button, toolbar.progessBar and toolbar.spinner are all nil.

I know the elements are not instantiated unless you display them.

Is there a way to make this work **without** displaying the object?

Comment: Did you connect xib views to `IBOutlets`?

Comment: yes (added this to the question now)

Comment: Tried MyToolbar *toolbar = [[MyToolbar alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyToolbar"]?

Comment: Did you connect the views to File's owner outlet? Try to remove the File's owner or connections and connect the views to MyToolbar.h outlets. I tried and it's working.

Comment: @Anil - there is no such method on a toolbar.

Comment: @GonjiDev - BRILLIANT! That’s it. Like I said I am still learning interface builder. Please add this comment of yours as an answer, so I can accept! THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you connect the views to File's owner outlet? Try to remove the File's owner or connections and connect the views to MyToolbar.h outlets. I tried and it's working.